# Regex to get values from a string using C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, match

I have posted this earlier but did not give clear information on what i was trying to achieve.

I am trying get values from a string using Regex in c#. I am not able to understand why some values i could get and some i can not using a similar approach.

Please find the code snippet below. 
Kindly let me know what i am missing.
Thanks in advance.

```
string text = "0*MAO-001*20160409*20160408*Encounter Data Duplicates Report       *     *ENC000200800400120160407*PRO*PROD*";

//toget the value 20160409 from the above text
//this code works fine
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"([0][*]MAO[-][0][0][1].*?[*](?<Value>\d+)[*])");
Match match = pattern.Match(text);
string Value = match.Groups["Value"].Value.ToString();



//to get the value ENC000200800400120160407 from the above text
// this does not work and gives me nothing
Regex pattern2 = new Regex(@"([0][*]MAO[-][0][0][1].*?[*].*?[*].*?[*].*?[*].*?[*](?<Value2>\d+)[*])");
Match match2 = pattern.Match(text);
string Value2 = match.Groups["Value2"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: try with this for 2nd regex :- `([0][*]MAO[-][0][0][1].*?[*].*?[*].*?[*].*?[*].*?[*](?<Value2>\w+)[*])`

Comment: wow .. thanks .. it worked .. do u want to post it as answer.. what is "w+" for ?

Comment: You should split on `*` instead of using specific field validation that could miss something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this for 2nd regex

```
([0][*]MAO[-][0][0][1].*?[*].*?[*].*?[*].*?[*].*?[*](?<Value2>\w+)[*])
```

`\w` is any character from set `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. You were using only `\d` which searches for digits `[0-9]` which was not the case

***[C# Code](http://ideone.com/eqTkJu)***

Answer (score 1):

It looks your file is '*' delimitered.

You can use one single regex to catch all the values

Try use

```
((?<values>[^\*]+)\*)
```

as your pattern.

All these values will be catched in values array.

**----Update add c# code-----**

```
string text = "0*MAO-001*20160409*20160408*Encounter Data Duplicates Report       *     *ENC000200800400120160407*PRO*PROD*";
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<values>[^\*]+)\*");
var matches = pattern.Matches(text);
string Value = matches[3].Groups["values"].Captures[0];
string Value2 = matches[6].Groups["values"].Captures[0];
```

Comment: I think you had it right the first time. To use the capture collection though, it should be quantified `(?:(?<values>[^\*]*)\*)+`

Answer (score 0):

In your second try at using the regex, you are matching with `pattern` and not `pattern2`.

```
Match match2 = pattern.Match(text);
string Value2 = match.Groups["Value2"].Value.ToString();
```

You are also using the `Groups` from `match` and not `match2`.

This is why it is important to name your variables something meaningful to what they represent. Yes it may be a "pattern" but what does that pattern represent. When you use variables that are vaguely named it creates issues like these.

Comment: You are right .. that was a blunder.. thanks for correcting.. but the pattern2 is not getting me the result as well

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, but the field you're looking for contains letters and digits.

This is your second regex kind of fixed.

`([0][*]MAO[-][0][0][1].*?[*](?:.*?[*]){4}(?<Value2>.*?)[*])`

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      [0] [*] MAO [-] [0] [0] [1] .*? [*] 

      (?: .*? [*] ){4}

      (?<Value2> .*? )              # (2)
      [*] 
 )                             # (1 end)
```

To make it a little less busy, this might be better

`(0\*MAO-001.*?\*(?:[^*]*\*){4}(?<Value2>[^*]*)\*)`